# windows server reboots automatically after scheduled updates

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I have 5 different asp.net applications running on windows server 2003. The server reboots automatically after installing scheduled updates from Microsoft.

I'm a developer and have admin rights on server for deployment purpose and there is networking guy who maintenance the server. When I informed this issue to him he said nothing can be done on this. Updates has to happen on schedule and if he forces the system not to reboot after installing updates it's a risk and there can be attacks on server.

But my concern is such random reboot affects all 5 application and this is major issue. So is there any solution to this?

Also my second question is there any log where I can see when server was shutdown and what was the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my concern is such random reboot affects all 5 application and this is major issue. So > is there any solution to this?

Get more servers.

This is not a technical but an organizational issue. You HAVE to patch, for security reasons, and if the patch needs a reboot, it NEEDS to happen.

You dont want your software not to be available? have multiple machines work the applications and have them reboot one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit group policy to change automatic reboots (are your servers in a domain?):
gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > "No auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Updates installations"
Your second question, you should be able to go through your event log this.

Answer (score 1):

I never let my servers automatically install updates. I let them download, then I install them on less critical servers so if one does not reboot due to a bad patch, I don't have a dozen servers all down at the same time. This possibility is VERY rare, but there have been bad patches released in the past. Then a firm reboot time should be enforced. That is the first thing your administrator should consider.

You did not say if these 5 applications were in production (I have to assume they are), although you mentioned you were a developer, so they could be for development only. If there is a huge amount of money lost, or customers are severely affected, you could consider installing a cluster. It is certainly more expensive, but you can then bring down each node of the cluster, without bringing down server. You then bring it back up and do the others.